# Does how the ghost look like can give you the answer as to what it is?

Tags: phasmophobia

When you can see the ghost, is the model used a good way to know what ghost you are dealing with, or are the models unrelated to the current ghost?

Comment: There are really only two ways to tell the ghost type:  1. Evidence. 2. Behaviors.

Comment: For that matter, only specific ghosts can be determined by behaviors, such as how Phantoms instantly vanish if you take a photo of them or how Wraiths don't leave footprints in salt (although they still leave impressions).

Comment: Of what ive seen only one can be determined by what model it uses. The phantom. Because its the only one that might appear just like a member of your team. But that is pretty close to behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model of ghosts are unrelated of types of ghost

In parallel, same ghost names doesnt mean is the same type of ghost every time

source: own experience (error and trial)

Answer (score 4):

While it is true for mostly every ghost type the model provides no information, since when the other answer was posted there is actually a ghost type now that can be determined by its model.

While hunting, an Obake has a 1/15 chance to swap to a different model every time its model flickers (before swapping back to its original model on the next flicker). If you notice the ghost blinking into a different model while it hunts, it likely means it is an Obake (or a Mimic pretending to be an Obake).